# View content is not displayed correctly after redirected in controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a action method in the controller and two views in different language.

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id, string languageName)
    {
        var view = "Welcome_en";
        if (languageName == "Spanish")
            view = "Welcome_es";
        return View(view, model);
    }
```

The default languageName is "English".(In `RouteConfig.cs` defaults part). So at the beginning, the page is loaded at `http://localhost:12091/Some/sssf6bda-9r5e-64d7-9bd2-63c2te616adb`.

And I saw the view was Welcome_en.cshtml. in that view I have a dropdown menu for languages to switch active language. I select Spanish then make an ajax call.

```
$("#Languages").change(function () {
            var activeLanguage= $(this).find('option:selected').val();
               $.ajax({
                      url: "/Some/Index",
                      datatype: "text",
                data: { id: '@Model.Guid', languageName: activeLanguage  },
                type: "POST",
                success: function () {
                    console.log('Success')
                }
               })
```

Then I saw the code entered the controller again. The view to be displayed should be Welcome_es.cshtml.

[image: 1]

The view Welcome_es.cshtml basically is same as Welcome_en.cshtml. The difference is the content in different language. And I set break points in  Welcome_es.cshtml, it did reached. However the final displayed result is still same as Welcome_en.cshtml.

I am not sure why it shows the English view's content, I cleaned the cookies but it is same. Also I set a break point in English page, it didn't go to there when the language was "Spanish".

Comment: What is the value of of languageName when entering the controller action? Do a watch on the languageName parameter

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is making the ajax call, but is **not using the response** coming from that call.

You should return the partial view result and use that to update the relevant part of your DOM to see the changes. You can do that in the success event of the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Some/Index",
    data: { id: '@Model.Guid', languageName: activeLanguage },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
        $("#someDiv").html(response);
    }
});
```

Assuming you have a div with id `someDiv` present in your page, the above code will update the inner html of that element with the response coming from your ajax call, which is the html markup generated by the corresponding views (based on the language name you are passing from client side)

I also noticed that you are calling the same action method for your normal page load and the ajax call. In that case, what are you trying to achieve with the ajax call ? You could simply reload the page. No need of ajax.

```
$(function() {

    $("#Languages").change(function() {
        var activeLanguage = $(this).val();
        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("index","Home")?languageName=" 
                                   + activeLanguage +"&id=@Guid.NewGuid()";
    });

});
```

If you are using a page reload, you might want to select the dropdown with the selection from previous page. You may use the Html.DropDownListFor helper with a view model for your page to address this issue.

Add a new property to your view model to store the selected language.

```
public class YourPageViewModel
{
    // Your other existing properties goes here

    public string SelectedLanguage { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your GET action method, you should set the SelectedLanguage property value based on your method parameter.

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id, string languageName)
{
    var view = "Welcome_en";
    if (languageName == "Spanish")
        view = "Welcome_es";

     var model = new YourPageViewModel();
     model.SelectedLanguage = languageName;

    return View(view, model);
}
```

Now in your view, use the `DropDownListFor` helper method

```
@model YourPageViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLanguage, languages,
                                                new { @class = "form-control" });
```

*Assuming `languages` is a list of `SelectListItem`'s. Replace it with the collection you have to render the dropdown items.*

The helper will render the dropdown with the name and id `SelectedLanguage`. So make sure you update that in your javasacript as well.

```
$(function() {

    $("#SelectedLanguage").change(function() {
        var activeLanguage = $(this).val();
        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("index","Home")?languageName=" 
                                   + activeLanguage +"&id=@Guid.NewGuid()";
    });

});
```

Comment: I have a bunch of places(elements). So how to do that?

Comment: What you mean by bunch of places  ? Can you be more specific ? Also read the last para of my answer ? Why are you making the ajax call ?

Comment: I meant in your answer `$("#someDiv")`. It only changes one place. I have `someDiv1`, `someDiv2` etc. How to reload the page? I make the ajax call because I want to pass the parameter `activeLanguage` to the controller.

Comment: There is no need of ajax if you simply want to reload the page using the selected language. See the updated answer.

Comment: Not sure why it is not working. It still shows English page. If using reload, it causes the new issue. My drop down list is created again. I have `@Html.DropDownList("Languages", new SelectList(Model.Languages).ToList())` in a div. In this case, even I select Spanish, it is forced to switched to English in the drop down after I click Spanish. English is in  the top in the`Model.Languages`.

Comment: You need to use the `DropDownListFor` helper method. See the updated answer.

Comment: Still wrong. The SelectedLanguage is always "English". `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLanguage, new SelectList(Model.Languages).ToList(),
                                                new { @class = "form-control" })`; Is it right? Model.Languages is IList type.

Comment: What is `Model.Languages` ? As long as your option's value attribute matches with the value in SelectedLanguage property value, it will be selected

Comment: The issue is that in client side the selctedLanguage is Spanish. But in controller it is "English". It seems that the selected value is not passed into the action correctly.

Comment: So when user reloads ( via the change event of dropdown), is it having the correct value for the languageName parameter in querystring ? Then it should work as long as you are setting the `SelectedLanguage` property value to that. Also i do not know what is in `Model.Languages`. The helper needs a list of `SelectListItem` s to render the dropdown correctly.

Comment: It is `public IList<string> Languages { get; set; }`

Comment: Then it should work. I just copied and pasted the code and it worked. Looks like you have some other code which you have not shown is altering the behavior

Comment: I have the default route. `            routes.MapRoute("WelcomeRoute", "Home/{id}/{languageName}",
                            defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", languageName="English" });'. Not sure if it is causing the issue.

Comment: I think that  `new SelectList(Model.Languages).ToList()` is doing bad things. The order in `Model.Languages` was initialized at the beginning. Every time you new up the list, the English is still the default one. Because on change event doesn't change the order in `Model.Languages`.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX request is returning your view, but you aren't doing anything with it. If your view is a partial then you can change the success callback in your AJAX call to update the part of the page which the HTML should replace.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Some/Index",
  datatype: "text",
  data: { id: '@Model.Guid', languageName: activeLanguage  },
  type: "POST",
  success: function (html) {
    $('.partial').html(html);
  }
});
```

Or if the view is really a full page then don't use AJAX to make the request.

Comment: It is not a partial view.